# why high traffic sites use serial subdomains for fetching data?

Tags: subdomain

I've seen so many sites like pinterest,G+, etc that use different subdomains to fetch desired data. why would they do that? Is there any difference between one static subdomain an subdomain as below for pinterest:

`media-cahce-ec0.pinterest.com

media-cahce-ec1.pinterest.com

media-cahce-ec2.pinterest.com

.

.

.

media-cahce-ec9.pinterest.com`

I appreciate in advance for any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple: Each sub domain refers to a different server. Ping them and you'll see the IPs are different. This is a **load balancer** so that the the web server doesn't have to handle the traffic of the images and downloads.

[image: Pinging two different servers]

Comment: media-cahce-ec0.pinterest.com and media-cahce-ec3.pinterest.com refers to one ip address, is there any reason for that?

Comment: it is probably the load balancer's IP. You won't see the internal cluster IPs.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot where you can see the ping request and the different IPs.

Comment: Also, according to the HTTP standard, browsers are allowed to use and do use more connections to different sub domains, even if the underlying IP is the same. This reduces the load time somewhat.